# Unable to localize xib in pods through xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, xib

I'm trying to localize xib through xcode.

When I select xib and hit the localize button in the File Inspector, xcode should create .strings file for the xib. In my case it is creating the another .xib file but not .strings file.

[image]

[image]

What I expect is:

[image]

[image]

**Note**: I can localize the xibs in my project.But I am not able to do for the xibs in the pods directory.

Answer (score 0):

I need to check the Use Base Internalization option below the Localization option in xcode.

[image]